# XSLT/XML nested for-each looping

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I have this xml file that I have created based off of information on a website. I will post a simplified version due to it containing a lot of information.

It is meant to use a xslt file to display and mimic an example of a college or university course which is structured like this:
there is multiple courses to be displayed so thats why it begins with courses then we have course to store each course.

There is course info here like teacher and other descriptions. Then we move to the year, and courses can have any number of years which is why we put year ynum="1" and every year has 2 semesters. Within the semesters there are multiple units so we put units/unit to store them.

This is the target output I want it to look like to give you an idea.

I have all that information stored in the xml and this is the output I want to achieve through xslt but am unsure how to start it on this level: http://puu.sh/80sBi/0107a6264e.png

Here is my Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Courses.xslt"?>

<courses>
  <course>computing
    <course_info></course_info>
    <teacher etc>
      <details></details>
    </teacher etc>

  <year ynum="1">
   <semester snum="1">
    <units>
     <unit>
        <code></code>
        <title></title>     <!-- this is the "description" table title -->
        <credit_points></credit_points>
     </unit>
     <unit>
        <code></code>
        <title></title>
        <credit_points></credit_points>
     </unit>
   </units>
 </semester>
 <semester snum="2">
  <units>
   <unit>
      <code></code>
      <title></title>
      <credit_points></credit_points>
   </unit>
 </units>
 </semester>
</year>
<year ynum="2">
  <semester snum="1">
    <units>
      <unit>
        <code></code>
        <title></title>
        <credit_points></credit_points>
      </unit>
    </units>
    </semester>
    <semester snum="2">
     <units>
      <unit>
      </unit>
     </units>
    </semester>
   </year>
  </course>
 </courses>
```

My failed attempt at a xslt file :/ any advice or help would be greatly appreciated as I can't seem to wrap my head around how to get the loops working for an example like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<body>
<h2>Course information</h2>



 <xsl:for-each select="courses/course">
 <strong>Course:</strong><xsl:value-of select="course"/><br />
   <strong>Code:</strong><xsl:value-of select="code"/><br />
   <strong>Course Coordinaotr</strong><xsl:value-of select="fname"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="sname"/></li>



   <table border="0">
   <tr>
   <th>unit</th>
   <th>description</th>
   <th>Credit Points</th>
   </tr>

   <xsl:for-each select="year/semester">
   <tr>
   <td><strong>Client ID:</strong><xsl:value-of select="unit_code"/></td>
   <td><strong>OrderDate:</strong><xsl:value-of select="unit_title"/></td>
   <td><strong>Quantity Ordered:</strong><xsl:value-of select="cp"/></td>
   <td><strong>Order Status:</strong><xsl:value-of select="additional_link"/></td>

   </xsl:for-each>
   </tr>


   </table>
 </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: I was hoping someone could share some resources or examples of XSLT dealing with the XML similar to the above to transform the data into something like this http://puu.sh/80sBi/0107a6264e.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it is better to use **xsl:apply-templates** in this situation, rather than **xsl:for-each**. Template matching is one of the main strengths of XSLT. It reduces indentation and can make the XSLT much cleaner. So, instead of doing `<xsl:for-each select="courses/course">`, do this

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="courses/course" />
```

You would then have a template matching **course** where you would output any main header information, then select the **year** elements

```
<xsl:template match="course">
    <strong>Course:</strong> <xsl:value-of select="text()" /><br />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="year" />
</xsl:template>
```

The **year** template would be similar, although it looks like you want to output year information per semester. Therefore your **year** template could look like this

```
<xsl:template match="year">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="semester" />
</xsl:template>
```

And then the **semester** template would start to look this this

```
<xsl:template match="semester">
    <strong>Year:</strong><xsl:value-of select="../@ynum"/><br />
    <strong>Semester:</strong><xsl:value-of select="@snum"/><br />
```

(Strictly speaking, you could probably drop the **year** template, and just do `<xsl:apply-templates select="year/semester" />` in this case).

And then it is just a case of selecting the **unit** elements in a similar manner for your table rows.

Try this XSLT as a starter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
        <body>
        <h2>Course information</h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="courses/course" />
        </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="course">
        <strong>Course:</strong> <xsl:value-of select="text()" /><br />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="year" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="year">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="semester" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="semester">
        <strong>Year:</strong><xsl:value-of select="../@ynum"/><br />
        <strong>Semester:</strong><xsl:value-of select="@snum"/><br />
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <th>unit</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th>Credit Points</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="units/unit" />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="unit">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="code"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="credit_points"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are a legend! thanks a lot! we were originally told to stay away from templates as for-each loops were "better" but from your example I have been able to understand it much better and add a lot of new functionality to it.

once again very grateful for the explanation and example thanks!